# customize the header group using ag grid angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to create the table like below image using ag grid angular.[image: reference image]

But I am not able to match exactly like the above screenshot.
Please find the screenshot below which i have tried, I want to keep the column group name long header inside cell1 and cell2. Also same way I want to move column group name small header inside cell3. Also I have tried using row spanning and column spanning. But those are not working with table group headers.
[image]

Please find the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-kbrumu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have found a solution. We can change the layout by modifying the CSS.